# How come this code works for one app and not for the other?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to deploy a socket.io on my server. I used the same code for two different apps. What's strange is that the exact code of socket.io worked for the first app and not for the second, even though it's the same one.

Let me explain it further. When I compile the first server.js file with node, I get this:
[image]

However, when I put the exact same code of socket.io in the second app and compile it with Node, I get the following:
[image]
 As you can see there's no "info - socket.io started" or anything. Why is that?

Comment: Here's one wild guess.  You may be running different versions of the socket.io server code in the two apps.  Only pre-1.0 versions of socket.io default to have messages show up in the console.

Comment: jfriend00 : that's exactly it. But how can I fix it?

Comment: You would need to install the same version of socket.io for each app using NPM.  I prefer to install things locally (rather than shared global installations) so I always know exactly what each app is running with.

Answer (score 1):

Making my comment into an answer since it led to the solution.

It looks like you are running different versions of socket.io in your two apps since only the pre-1.0 version of socket.io outputs info to the console by default.

So, to make both your apps works the same, you need to make sure they are both using the same version of socket.io.  You can do that by using NPM to install socket.io locally (probably the current 1.x version) for each app.